Google signin HTML API redirect with data-state not working
I am using google signin (HTML API) in my application through redirect mode. But as per documentation, if we use 'data-state', it should post the value back in callback which is not happening, which i would need that state to capture it for other purpose back from google.
Documentation Reference

HTML
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>

<div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id=“xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com" data-context="signin" data-ux_mode="redirect" data-login_uri="http://localhost:8080/googlecallback" data-auto_prompt="false"></div>

<div class="g_id_signin" data-locale="en-GB" data-type="standard" data-width="350" data-shape="rectangular" data-theme="filled_blue" data-text="signin_with" data-state=“/profile” data-size="medium">

Google Console - Credentials configuration

Google Response POST
client_id=xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
credential=XXXXX
select_by=btn
g_csrf_token=XXXXXX

where state is missing from above google response referring to documentation. Kindly help me if i am missing something or?

Same issue here. It just stopped working all of a sudden.

If I change data-ux_mode from "redirect" to "popup", it works.

But popup mode won't work on iOS, right?

It will unless itp_support is false, see https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/itp

I'm confirming that this is a problem and a fix is in development.
If possible, sharing a Client ID will enable Google to more quickly verify that the fix works as intended.
Client IDs are public, included the site HTML source loaded by the browser and are generally safe to include in comments and code samples. Security is maintained by OAuth authorized origins and redirect URLs.

Kindly update us if fix is available in general!

I have the same problem. Where should I report my case?

The fix is now generally available, let me know if you're seeing failures or if everything is working as expected.

Now its working fine! Thanks
